# Xamarin IOS UI Thread Blocked to due cpu intensive method, tried Await/Async/Threading/Tasks nothing solved it. (see code below)

Tags: c#, xamarin

The GetJoints method responsible for retrieving the Keypoints from the prediction either blocks/impacts the UI. This occurs maybe 3,4 minutes after the application is running so its not noticeable on start up. If I remove the GetJoints method the UI is fine and the block/lag is not present. I am only using simple animations on the UI so nothing intensive, but we can see they start being blocked.

https://github.com/tyronelinton/samplygame/blob/main/AppDelegate.cs

//METHOD:

```
public static List<Joint> GetJoints(LightBuzz5Output prediction, int sourceWidth, int       sourceHeight)
    {
        var heatmaps = prediction.Final_heatmaps_0;
        var keypointCount = (int)heatmaps.Shape[2] - 1;
        var heatmapWidth = (int)heatmaps.Shape[3];
        var heatmapHeight = (int)heatmaps.Shape[4];

        List<Joint> points = new List<Joint>();

        for (int i = 0; i < keypointCount; i++)
        {
            int positionX = 0;
            int positionY = 0;

            float confidence = 0.0f;

            for (int x = 0; x < heatmapWidth; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < heatmapHeight; y++)
                {
                    int index = y + heatmapHeight * (x + heatmapWidth * i);

                    if (heatmaps[index].FloatValue > confidence)
                    {
                        confidence = heatmaps[index].FloatValue;

                        positionX = x;
                        positionY = y;
                    }
                }
            }

            points.Add(new Joint
            {
                X = (float)sourceWidth * (float)positionY / (float)heatmapHeight,
                Y = (float)sourceHeight * (float)positionX / (float)heatmapWidth,
                Confidence = confidence
            });
        }

        return points;
    }
```

//USAGES:
private void Process(UIImage image)
{
UIImage resizedImage = image.Scale(new CGSize(256, 256));

```
            CVPixelBuffer buffer = Utilities.GetBuffer(resizedImage.CGImage);

            NSError error;
            var prediction = model.GetPrediction(buffer, out error);

            List<Joint> joints = null;

            if (error != null)
            {
                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(error);
            }
            else
            {
                joints = Utilities.GetJoints(prediction, width, height);
            }            
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide your solution with `Task`s which is not worked for you?

Comment: await Task.Run(async () => await GetJoints(prediction, (int)image.Size.Width, (int)image.Size.Height));       //This still blocked the UI. the GetJoints method runs every second.

Comment: Task.Run(()=> GetJoints());   //this also blocked UI

Comment: How do you schedule running it every second? Are you handling situation if previous run didn't complete yet? If you don't you are possibly accumulating many overlapping backround processing which hangs your UI after some time.

Comment: It is called by DidOutputSampleBuffer callback inside that method I call GetJoints, i limit it to 1 call per second by a datetime check. I'm sure that its not overlapping as I have an HasCompleted bool preventing calling until set back to true at the end of the GetJoints method

Comment: I think that part of code you provided is not enough to diagnose your problem, too many things involved that we cannot see.

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev It is only 1 .cs file please could you take a look for me I have been trying to solve for over a week https://github.com/tyronelinton/samplygame/blob/main/AppDelegate.cs

Comment: As your description, it's maybe a memory problem, you'd better take a debug on it, and check which take too much resource.